# Google maps geocode - error_message : "Invalid request. Invalid 'latlng' parameter."

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to request a Cityname by sending "latlng" parameters go google-maps like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  placeMarker(event.latLng);
  var clicklat = parseFloat(event.latLng.lat());
  var clicklng = parseFloat(event.latLng.lng());
  var latlng = {lat: clicklat, lng: clicklng}; 
  console.log(latlng);

  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
    params:{
      latlng: latlng,   
      language: 'de',
      key:'your_api_key'

    }
  })
```

But sadly i get this error back:

```
{error_message: "Invalid request. Invalid 'latlng' parameter.", results: [], status: "INVALID_REQUEST"}
error_message
:
"Invalid request. Invalid 'latlng' parameter."
results
:
[]
status
:
"INVALID_REQUEST"
```

Can someone please explain this to me? - I´m a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

### This is how I was able to solve my issue

```
getAddress(params) {
   let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=' + this.google_api_key + '&latlng=' + params.lat + ',' + params.long;
   return this.GET(url);
}

GET(url) {
  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

#### Basically these have to follow this order

- API Key
- Latitude
- Longitude

Answer (score 0):

LatLng is a google Map Object, you can define it like you want, you have to respect the correct syntax :

```
var locat = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but it did not work. "lat" and "lng" in your example are my variables "clicklat" and "clicklng", right?

Answer (score 0):

you already had the latLng in event, so just use it in the request:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

placeMarker(event.latLng);
//var clicklat = parseFloat(event.latLng.lat());
//var clicklng = parseFloat(event.latLng.lng());
//var latlng = {lat: clicklat, lng: clicklng}; 
//console.log(latlng);

axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
  params:{
    latlng: event.latLng,   
    language: 'de',
    key:'your_api_key'

  }
})
```